# how to display select box options without selecting select box

Tags: html, jquery, css, html-select

There is a requirement in my project like.,
I have select box in desktop view and in mobile only options has to be displayed.

I got stuck how to display all the options without selecting select box .

```
<h3>Desktop View</h3>

<select name="carmakes" id="carmakes">
        <option selected='selected' value="0">Car makes</option>
        <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>

<br/><br/><br/><br/>


<h3>Mobile View</h3>


<option selected='selected' value="0">Car makes</option>
<option value="bmw">BMW</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
```

Thanks 
[image]

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/veby5q82/)

Answer (score 3):

Just give `multiple` for your select box and it'll display like that...

```
<select multiple name="carmakes" id="carmakes">
        <option selected='selected' value="0">Car makes</option>
        <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
```